# Setting Authentication Manager in Atlassian Crowd 2.8.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, atlassian-crowd

I am trying to integrate Atlassian Crowd with Spring Security.

The available code samples on this are very few, especially for Spring Boot. I have only found [this](https://tools.regenstrief.org/stash/projects/CORE/repos/sensitive-data-tool/browse/src/main/java/org/regenstrief/core/sensitivedata/CrowdSecurityConfig.java?at=0cdfc81).

This example calls class `CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl` method `setAuthenticationManager()`, which has vanished in the haze in version 2.8.0 (compare [2.8.0](https://docs.atlassian.com/crowd/latest/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/springsecurity/user/CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl.html) and [2.7.1](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/2.7.1/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/springsecurity/user/CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl.html) APIs).

Question: how should I replace the method call in 2.8.0 to make things work?

Comment: See [crowd-spring-security-sample](https://bitbucket.org/jwalton/crowd-spring-security-sample) for another example, albeit one that's not up to date yet either.

Comment: Thanks. However, I did not find anything related to this problem in the example. My current understanding is that 2.8.0 does not require anything to replace the method call, my code is almost fully up and running already. What worries me still is the lack of code examples and community support for the integration of Crowd with Spring Security (already looking for other alternatives)...

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, there's no need to replace this method call. The `AuthenticationManager` is no longer needed by the `CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl` in 2.8.

[This `applicationContext-security.xml`](https://bitbucket.org/jwalton/crowd-spring-security-sample/src/48f29b1b73a740b9bd57b6d3814d708de1842689/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml) shows a working example of wiring with Spring.